# Beaglebone Black not Working After Failed Attempt at Flashing eMMC

Tags: beagleboneblack

Following this [guide](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started), I got my Beaglebone Black Rev C working before updating to latest images.
I can connect to it using SSH and  192.168.7.2. I was able to code directly using SSH, but not from Cloud9. According to [this](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors/f/791/t/283187?Problems-using-BeagleBone-Black-and-Cloud9-IDE), I need to update the OS to the latest images (by following the linked guide).

I do step 0.A to 0.E without any issue. When I did this:

> Insert SD card into your (powered-down) board, hold down the USER/BOOT button (if using Black) and apply power, either by the USB cable or 5V adapter.

I try to connect using SSH, but the OS did not changed. I then try to flash it to eMMC by following this [step](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Flashing_eMMC). After 2 hours, it still not finished (USR LEDs still running left and right). Then I disconnect the power and remove the SD card.

After that, the board only detected as COM Port and that is not even working.
How do I make it working again? Or, is it possible to factory reset?

Additional Information:
I'm using 64-bit Windows 10 Home
I'm using 256GB SanDisk SD Card

Answer (score 2):

The good news, it's not possible to damage the BBB this way permanently. It's fairly easy to recover from once you understand the underlying mechanics.

There are a couple of things that you should do to make your BeagleBone experience better:

- **Get a UART adapter to plug into the debug UART**

  - This is a total life-saver for many embedded tasks
  - It allows you to see the *whole* boot process (U-Boot, Kernel, Userspace)
  - Cables/Adapters https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_Serial
  - The cheapest suitable adapters cost less than 1€/1$ on ebay/Aliexpress/Banggood/etc.
  - UART0: https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#BeagleBone_Black_Connector_and_Switch_Locations [image: Important connectors and buttons on the BBB]
- Wipe the eMMC

  - Boot from SD card and execute `sudo blkdiscard /dev/mmcblk1`
  - This erases all contents of the eMMC storage, quickly
- Either keep booting from MicroSD card or Flash to eMMC as in the link you pointed out.